# walking simple tree in python

Tags: python, graph, tree

i'im trying to reconstruct some linear data with a 'parent' relation into a useable simple (non-cyclic, non-duplicate nodes) tree, however my code doesn't appear to work beyond a couple of levels.

basically i would like output like:

```
{
 '1': {'10': {}, '11': {}, '12': {}},
 '2': {'20': { '200': {}, '201': {} }},
 '301': {}
}
```

but instead i get this:

```
{
 '1': {'10': {}, '11': {}, '12': {}},
 '2': {'20': {}},
 '200': {},
 '201': {},
 '301': {}
}
```

my code is as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import logging
from pprint import pprint

def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)
def dicts(t): return {k: dicts(t[k]) for k in t}

def walk_to( node, tree, depth=0 ):
    pre = ' '*depth
    logging.error("%swalk to %s" % (pre,node))
    for k in tree:
        logging.error("%s k=%s" % (pre,k))
        if k == node:
            logging.error("%s   found %s! %s" % (pre,node,tree[node]))
            return tree[node]
        else:
            w = walk_to( node, tree[k], depth=depth+1 )
            logging.error("%s  w %s" %(pre,w))
            if w:
                logging.error("%s   out %s" % (pre,w))
                return w
    return None

def attach( node, parent, tree ):
    logging.error("add %s at %s" % (node,parent))
    t = walk_to( parent, tree )
    if t == None:
        tree[node]
    else:
        t[node]
    logging.error("\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':    

    topology = tree()

    attach( '1', None, topology )
    attach( '10', '1', topology )
    attach( '11', '1', topology )
    attach( '12', '1', topology )
    attach( '2', None, topology )
    attach( '20', '2', topology )
    attach( '200', '20', topology )
    attach( '201', '20', topology )    
    attach( '301', '30', topology )    

    logging.error("%s" % (pprint(dicts(topology))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want:

```
        if w is not None:
            logging.error("%s   out %s" % (pre,w))
            return w
```

instead of just `if w`.  the empty dict is evaluating as false (empty collections in python are falsey) and so you're failing to return properly from your recursion.  note how the "out" message is never printed in the original.

it would also be more standard to replace `t == None` with `t is None` - None is a singleton value.